# Compaq Presario v6500 won't boot from CD

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, compact-disc

Trying to install Windows XP on a new HDD in a Compaq Presario 6500 notebook (model no 6501XX, originally shipped with Windows Vista 32bit).

However despite my efforts the computer refuses to boot from CD. I have tried:

- Booting from several (bootable installer) CD/DVD's (even a HP Windows 7 restore DVD)
- Checking that CD is bootable in BIOS
- Using an external (USB connected) CD/DVD drive
- Updated the BIOS to latest version (Phoenix BIOS V34)

When Windows is booted from HDD there seem to be nothing wrong with the internal DVD drive, it can read and burn CD/DVD's. Also I can confirm that the external CD reader is fine.

On startup, pressing F9 brings the boot device menu. It only shows the internal hard disk as an option, whatever disc I put in. I have searched the web and HP troubleshooting without luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: The BIOS may be corrupt. Try flashing it with the latest BIOS.

Comment: I assume you have changed the boot order in the BIOS to boot from the CD first?

Comment: @terdon Sure, boot order is not the issue. Also the F9 boot menu doesn't even show the CD as an option even though I can confirm that BIOS option Boot from CD is enabled.

Comment: @CharlieRB Tried this. Updated the old V7 Phoenix BIOS to latest for the model, V34. But still the same issue, no boot from CD.

Comment: So I'm assuming WinToFlash didn't help for a USB-based install to C:? Can you post camera snaps of the boot order menu in your BIOS?

Comment: @Karan I still haven't had my chance to try WinToFlash. Will try that next week, the computer is at my office so I can't proceed during the weekend. I posted this question because I'm still curious why a standard CD installation just won't work as the CD player seem to be working fine when the computer runs on the old HDD. Of course I tried to change the boot order in various ways. The current setting is first CD/DVD drive, then all USB and floppy options and last the internal HDD. But it never boots off the CD.

Comment: I've seen some strange BIOSes have multiple boot order menus, which is why I was asking for pics to make sure that's not the case here. Also, have you got a CD/DVD to boot successfully on another PC with that same external drive?

Comment: @Karan The BIOS only has one simple boot order menu. Also pressing F9 at startup brings a simple menu that would let you override any such settings. (But in that menu there is no CD/DVD at all). But I can add some pictures next week to show you. Good point also to check if the external CD could boot another PC. Will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Might be on your SATA setting as AHCI. You can try that one, or try the IDE mode